# How to make vertical line like this?

Tags: html, css

I have a contact info list like this: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heccc.png)

How to make the vertical line that separates email and hotline like in the picture, many thank

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking additional questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the pipe character from your keyboard. It looks like that:

```
|
```

-OR-

You can split the line into 2 elements and add a border to one of them.
Just an example:

HTML

```
<div class="left">Email</div><div class="right">Hotline</div>
```

CSS

```
.left { display: inline-block; border-right: 1px solid black; padding: 0 10px; }
.right { display: inline-block; padding: 0 10px; }
```

Comment: the CSS way makes the vertical line stick with the "email", is there any way to fix that?

Comment: @HungPG you can add padding and/or margin inside both div elements.